# Does Spring @Qualifier resolves name among all beans or only among beans that share the qualified type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring and was wondering how @Qualifier resolves for DI.

If I have an interface for Reading external data with implementations for reading local files (to read config files for example) and reading from database (reading the business data for example), hiding the actual technical detail from the caller (is it a DB or is a LocalFile or something else, doesnt matter interface contract is fullfilled).

```
public interface Reader { }

@Component
@Qualifier("LocalFileReader")
public class LocalFileReader implements Reader { }

@Component
@Qualifier("DbReader")
public class DbReader implements Reader { }
```

When I want to inject a Reader implementation

```
public class MyService {    
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("LocalFileReader")
   private Reader reader;    
}
```

When Spring will try to find the Reader implementation, will it look among all the defined qualifiers for all Beans, or will it only look among the qualifiers for the Reader implementations ?

In the second case, does it mean I can use the same "LocalFile" qualifier on different, unrelated  beans, like implementations of `Reader` and implementations of `Writer` for example ?

```
public class MyService {    
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("LocalFile")
   private Reader reader;  

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("LocalFile")
   private Writer writer;  
}
```

It doesnt bring much gain over doing `@Qualifier("LocalFileReader")` and `@Qualifier("LocalFileWriter")` but it helps me understand how it works. And if I'm right so far, is there a way to tell once "for this entire object use the local file beans" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When Spring will try to find the Reader implementation, will it look among all the defined qualifiers for all Beans, or will it only look among the qualifiers for the Reader implementations?

Nope, the `@Autowired` annotation searches only for the beans of the required type. If there are multiple implementations, the `@Qualifier` annotation helps to select the particular one. In other words, if you have multiple beans sharing the same name but differ in type (i.e. only one of them is qualified by type), the `@Qualifier` annotation is not needed.

> In the second case, does it mean I can use the same "LocalFile" qualifier on different, unrelated beans, like implementations of Reader and implementations of Writer for example?

Of course, you can.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring resolves autowired entries by type. If more than one bean of the same type is available in the container but it can't resolve using Qualifiers or other mechanism, the framework will throw `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`

So, for your question, it will look for implementations of `Reader`.

I am not sure if you can use same qualifier names for different types but, if you want some similar functionality, you need to look at [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) where each profile decides on the Bean that you want to inject for dependency